# PHP - How do I get this to print out in a table from an reference number?

Tags: php, postgresql, shopping-cart

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="' . $row['0'] .  '" /></td>';
```

Hi, I'm trying to get a reference number which comes from a an array called items from another page as shown above, and to find it in the table and print out the reference row, like "Title,Platform...." into another table, but I can't seem to get it working...any help be appreciated

```
if (isset($_POST['items'])) {
    $n = count($_POST['items']);

    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++){
      //  echo $_POST['items'][$i]; 
    }

    $items = array();
    foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item) {
        $items[] = pg_escape_string($con, $item);
    }

    if (!$_SESSION["selectingrows"]) {

        $item_string = "'" . implode("','", $items) . "'";

        $result = pg_query ($con, "SELECT title, platform, description, price FROM CSGames    WHERE 'refnumber' IN ($item_string)");

        while($rows = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['1'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['2'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['3'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['4'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u checked ur array `$row` contains the needed values...and also confirm that u have used the correct key names...like  `$rows['1']`,`$rows['']` must have the respecting values...

Comment: Is there a way I can check this? Because I'm assuming that I have manage from using the query that it finds the record by using the reference number and pulling 'title, platform' and that out? I just need to display them in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing, you need to put `{}` braces after your `while` loop.

Here is what you are doing:

```
while($rows = pg_fetch_assoc($result))

    echo"<tr>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['1'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['2'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['3'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['4'] . "</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
```

By not putting braces around the code after the `while` statement, here is what your code really does:

```
while($rows = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo"<tr>";
}
echo "<td>" . $rows['1'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['2'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['3'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['4'] . "</td>";
echo"</tr>";
```

You should always put braces in to define what code is in the while loop.

You want your code to be something like this:

```
while($rows = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $rows['1'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $rows['2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $rows['3'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $rows['4'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Format your code neatly and properly. By doing this your code is clearer and it is much easier to notice possible mistakes like the above. Always use braces for `if`, `while`, `for` statements. When putting an end line semicolon `;` put in a new line break. Indent your code correctly. It's little things like formatting that make coding easier.

Now the next problem I can see is the values you are getting from the `$rows` array:

```
    $rows['1'];
    $rows['2'];
    $rows['3'];
    $rows['4'];
```

This is trying to get something from the `$rows` array which has the *key* of string `'1'`.

Usually you access array values by index, which uses an integer beggining from `0`. Or you access it by a key.

Either you can try this:

```
    $rows[0];
    $rows[1];
    $rows[2];
    $rows[3];
```

Or this:

```
    $rows['title'];
    $rows['platform'];
    $rows['description'];
    $rows['price'];
```

Comment: Ah yeah, however the table is still not print though?

Comment: I've just added more to the answer. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah it make sense, I've tried the two ways, ($rows[0] and $rows['title']) and I still doesn't bring up the table..., am I going wrong else where or something?

Comment: Your going to have to debug your code. What you could do is check the content of the `$rows` array by calling `var_dump($rows)` in your while loop. This will print the contents of the array to screen. Or NULL if it's empty. If nothing is printed to the screen, the code is not getting to this stage. You could also try to remove `WHERE 'refnumber' IN ($item_string)` from your sql statement to see if this is the problem.